# python idiomatic python for loop if else statement

Tags: python, if-statement, for-loop, idioms

How can I use `else` statement in an idiomatic Python `for` loop? Without `else` I can write e.g.:

```
res = [i for i in [1,2,3,4,5] if i < 4]
```

The result is: `[1, 2, 3]`

The normal form of the above code is:

```
res = []
for i in [1,2,3,4,5]:
    if i < 4:
        res.append(i)
```

The result is the same as in idiomatic form: `[1, 2, 3]`

And I want this:

```
res = [i for i in [1,2,3,4,5] if i < 4 else 0]
```

I get `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`. The result should be: `[1, 2, 3, 0, 0]`
The normal code of this is:

```
res = []
for i in [1,2,3,4,5]:
    if i < 4:
        res.append(i)
    else:
        res.append(0)
```

The result is: `[1, 2, 3, 0, 0]`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You were close, you just have to move the ternary to the part of the list comprehension where you're creating the value.

```
res = [i if i < 4 else 0 for i in range(1,6)]
```